# How do I check what letters are in a substring using if then statements?

Tags: c#, if-statement, boolean, substring

I'm having the user input their name and then using substring to isolate the first letter. The console then prints something depending on what the first letter of the name is. How do I check what letter is being in the substring? This is what I have so far as a template.

```
        string  name,letter;

        Console.WriteLine("What name would you like to use?(please enter in lower case)");
        name = Console.ReadLine();
        letter=name.Substring(0, 1);
        if letter=a;
        {Console.WriteLine("hello a");}
        else
        {Console.Write("alternativemessage");}
```

Comment: are you asking for the syntax?

Comment: `if(letter=="a") ...` perhaps? You could also use `name.First()=='a'` or `name[0]=='a'`. Keep in mind that the string could be null or empty.

Comment: Thanks! It's working. Now just have to figure out how to group multiple letters together so each set has a different output.

Comment: @robbiek: maybe you want to delete this question since i don't see how it could be helpful for others in future. You could ask a different question for your new requirement.

Comment: @robbiek for grouping, check out the [switch](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/06tc147t.aspx) statement.

Answer (score 1):

```
string name = Console.ReadLine();
If (name[0] == 'a')
    {
        Console.WriteLine("ayy");
    }
Else
    {
        Console.WriteLine("nayy");
    }
```

Might want to add some checks for your strings not being null/empty/etc. when returned, but this should be fine.